# Problems in installing catkin_make on ROS 2

Tags: catkin-make

I finished installing ROS 2 Humble without problems, when I want to complete it with the `catkin_make` command it tells me that it is not installed

```
mb@mb-Lidar:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt install catkin
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt --fix-broken install» para corregirlo.
Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:
 python3-rosdistro-modules : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 python3-rospkg-modules : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-ament-cmake-core : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-qt-gui : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-ros2doctor : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-ros2pkg : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-rqt-gui : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-rqt-msg : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-rqt-plot : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-rqt-publisher : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
 ros-humble-rqt-shell : Depende: python3-catkin-pkg-modules pero no va a instalarse
E: Dependencias incumplidas. Intente «apt --fix-broken install» sin paquetes (o especifique una solución).
```

I try to install it with `sudo apt install catkin` and it gives me this error `E: Unfulfilled dependencies. Try "apt --fix-broken install" without packages (or specify a fix)`. Now, I can't move forward

```
mb@mb-Lidar:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias... Hecho
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Corrigiendo dependencias... Listo
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  cmake-extras python3-catkin python3-catkin-pkg ros-environment
Utilice «sudo apt autoremove» para eliminarlos.
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes adicionales:
  python3-catkin-pkg-modules
Se instalarán los siguientes paquetes NUEVOS:
  python3-catkin-pkg-modules
0 actualizados, 1 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 9 no actualizados.
503 no instalados del todo o eliminados.
Se necesita descargar 0 B/43.2 kB de archivos.
Se utilizarán 258 kB de espacio de disco adicional después de esta operación.
¿Desea continuar? [Y/n] y
(Leyendo la base de datos ... 298057 ficheros o directorios instalados
 actualmente.)
Preparando para desempaquetar .../python3-catkin-pkg-modules_1.0.0-1_a
ll.deb ...
Desempaquetando python3-catkin-pkg-modules (1.0.0-1) ...
dpkg: error al procesar el archivo /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-cat
kin-pkg-modules_1.0.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/_
_init__.py', que está también en el paquete python3-catkin-pkg 0.4.24-
2
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_1.0.0-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

ROS 2 uses `colcon`, whereas ROS 1 uses `catkin`. You are trying to install an unsupported package, which is causing the error.

Please install the `python3-colcon-common-extensions` package using the following command:

```
sudo apt install python3-colcon-common-extensions
```

Please look at [the official documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Colcon-Tutorial.html) for a better understanding.